# Скрипт проверяющий скорость хостинга

Tags: php, хостинг

Доброго

Сейчас использую определенный фреймворк(mPDF), загоняю его на хостинг, он формирует определенный файл(PDF на 100 листов). На странице выдает время выполнения скрипта. Ест-но разница скорости работы хостингов ощутима, скажем хостинг за 1$ и за 10-15$ в мес. Тест рассчитан не на то, что бы 10 человек зашли одновременно на сайт, и не на работу кэша mysql, а на чистый PHP.

Вопрос: есть ли какие то скрипты, достаточно простые, и достаточно информативные, что бы определить скорость работы хостинга?

p.s. думаю вопрос именно сюда, а не на рут код, т.к. ищу код. Просто иногда бывает, когда сайт отполировал до блеска, этого не хватает, и перед переездом на более быстрый хостинг - интересно проверить скорость нового.

p.p.s. прошу не предлагать ставить битрикс и довольствоваться внутренними тестами

Comment: раз Вам нужна библиотека mPDF, то и пользуйтесь ее как тестом. Это будет самый простой и информативный тест (в Вашем случае). Все остальные тесты будут синтетическими и не будут тестить то, что Вам действительно нужно.

Comment: > думаю вопрос именно сюда, а не на рут код, т.к. ищу код.

если ищите код, то вопрос в гугль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылки (можете поискать еще):

- [6 сервисов проверки вашего хостинга](http://gering111.com/6-servisov-hostinga/)
- [Как проверить скорость работы хостинга](http://seolife.in.ua/ru/2012/08/kak-proverit-skorost-raboty-hostinha.html)

Также как вариант запустите цикл в миллион итераций или сколько душа пожелает и измерьте скорость его выполнения через [microtime()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.microtime.php)